# Does GR reflect Aristotelian time?

Tags: general-relativity

This is really a philosophical question, which I've already asked at Phil.SE but I'm asking here with more physics detail.

In Newtonian Mechanics, space and time are independent of each other, and of motion; in that the geometry of space time is independent of the distribution of matter and energy and it's motion; does the same go for GR?

On the one hand, time is deliberately measured by motion, that of light; on the other hand there are solutions of GR that have [static spacetimes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_spacetime).

**edit**

Aristotle, *Physics IV.14*:

> The reason, then, why people think of time as the change of the heavenly sphere is because all other changes are measured by this change, and time too is measured by this change.

and Mach as quoted in Julian Barbours Paper [On the nature of time](https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.3489v1):

> It is utterly beyond our power to measure the changes of things by time ... time is an abstraction at which we arrive by means of the changes of things; made because we are not restricted to any one definite measure, all being interconnected.

Comment: Crossposted from http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/21980

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple notions of time in GR.  Typically when you write down a space you do so in some set of coordinates $(t,x,y,z)$.  The $t$ there is the *coordinate time*.  It marches forward forever, and doesn't care at all what the matter and energy content of the system may be.  This seems very similar to the Aristotelian time.

However, the fundamental principle of general relativity is that your particular choice of coordinates doesn't matter.  Your coordinate choice is really just a gauge freedom.  Physical systems experience their own *proper time* $\tau$ which certainly can be different for different observers, even if the spacetime is static!

So the answer to your question seems to be: both yes and no :)